# Cannot get value of property from extending class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two Java classes, one of which inherits from other. They are somewhat like the following:

**A.java:**

```
public class A {
    public String invocations[] = {"foo"};

    public A() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

**B.java:**

```
public class B extends A {
    public String invocations = {"bar", "baz"};

    public B() {
        super();
    }
}
```

In this example, assuming I create an instance of B and get its `invocations` property, it returns `{"foo"}` instead of the expected `{"bar", "baz"}`. Why is this, and how can I get the `{"bar", "baz"}`?

Comment: Your code, as written, will not even compile.  So how do you know what the behavior will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one variable hiding another one. You can refer to a variable in a super class by using a cast to the type explicitly. (I am assuming you fix the syntax errors)

```
public class Main {
    static class A {
        public String[] invocations = {"foo"};
    }

    static class B extends A {
        public String[] invocations = {"bar", "baz"};
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println("((A)b).invocations=" + Arrays.toString(((A) b).invocations));
        System.out.println("b.invocations=" + Arrays.toString(b.invocations));
    }
}
```

prints

```
((A)b).invocations=[foo]
b.invocations=[bar, baz]
```